# checking values from two tables?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I had two tables 
table1 contains a list of customer and their info and there is a customer id for each one 
table2 contains a list of request from all with and customer id for each request as foreign key

and i want to check the customer who has request and who is not

plz how should that be done logical is it possible to eqaul between two queries ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have two tables, the first with one row per customer, the other with zero to many rows per customer.  So you need two techniques: one to reduce the second table to one row per customer and the other to join that result set to the first table.  These techniques are an aggregating sub-query and an outer join respectively.

```
select c.customer_id
       , nvl(r.req_count, 0) as no_of_reqs
from   customer c
       left outer join ( select customer_id
                                , count(*)  as req_count
                         from   customer_req 
                         group by customer_id ) r
        on c.customer_id = r.customer_id
```